# Conversion from char* to std::string gives wrong symbols

Tags: c++

My code is:

```
std::string get_time() {
    char buf[20];
    std::time_t timestamp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    strftime(buf, 20, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", std::gmtime(&timestamp));
    
    std::cout<<buf<<std::endl;
    return std::string(buf, 20);
}

...

auto timestamp = get_time().c_str();
std::cout<<timestamp<<std::endl;
```

It should return current datetime in string format.
But what I get is:

```
17.10.2022 11:12:46
1!`u�I��22 11:12:46
```

So, the conversion beween char* and string works wrong. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `auto timestamp = get_time().c_str();` assignes a pointer to a temporary which is deleted at the end of the full expression (`;`) leaving a dangling pointer.  Instead use `std::cout << get_time().c_str() << std::endl;`.  Or `auto timestamp = get_time();` which will make a copy of the `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `get_time()` returns a `std::string`. Because nothing references this string, it gets deleted at the end of the line. Then, calling `get_time().c_str()` keeps a pointer to that string (see [`std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>::c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) on cppreference). However, that string isn't guaranteed to exist. Other processes have overwritten some of that memory, using it, and that is why you get those characters. You don't need to call `get_time.c_str()`, you can just output the `std::string` directly:

```py
std::string get_time() {
    char buf[20];
    std::time_t timestamp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    strftime(buf, 20, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", std::gmtime(&timestamp));
    
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
    return std::string(buf, 20);
}

...

auto timestamp = get_time();
std::cout << timestamp< < std::endl;
```